# pkgsrc's unzip is broken?

Tags: ubuntu, zip, pkgsrc

I'm trying to use pkgsrc on ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Installation was vary easy.

```
$ cvs -q -z3 -d anoncvs@anoncvs.NetBSD.org:/cvsroot checkout -P pkgsrc
$ ./bootstrap --unprivileged
```

Then I installed unzip package from source. It looked success too.

```
$ cd pkgsrc/archivers/unzip/
$ bmake
$ bmake install
$ which unzip
/home/xxxx/pkg/bin/unzip
```

However it didn't work when it was executed.

```
$ cd ~

$ ls
aaa.zip

$unzip aaa.zip
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.  Send
bug reports using http://www.info-zip.org/zip-bug.html; see README for details.

Usage: unzip [-Z] [-opts[modifiers]] file[.zip] [list] [-x xlist] [-d exdir]
  Default action is to extract files in list, except those in xlist, to exdir;
  file[.zip] may be a wildcard.  -Z => ZipInfo mode ("unzip -Z" for usage).

  -p  extract files to pipe, no messages     -l  list files (short format)
  -f  freshen existing files, create none    -t  test compressed archive data
  -u  update files, create if necessary      -z  display archive comment only
  -v  list verbosely/show version info       -T  timestamp archive to latest
  -x  exclude files that follow (in xlist)   -d  extract files into exdir
modifiers:
  -n  never overwrite existing files         -q  quiet mode (-qq => quieter)
  -o  overwrite files WITHOUT prompting      -a  auto-convert any text files
  -j  junk paths (do not make directories)   -aa treat ALL files as text
  -C  match filenames case-insensitively     -L  make (some) names lowercase
  -X  restore UID/GID info                   -V  retain VMS version numbers
  -K  keep setuid/setgid/tacky permissions   -M  pipe through "more" pager
See "unzip -hh" or unzip.txt for more help.  Examples:
  unzip data1 -x joe   => extract all files except joe from zipfile data1.zip
  unzip -p foo | more  => send contents of foo.zip via pipe into program more
  unzip -fo foo ReadMe => quietly replace existing ReadMe if archive file newer

$ echo $?
10

$ ls
aaa.zip
```

The error code was 10, [which means invalid options were specified on the command line](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/unzip.html#DIAGNOSTICS).
Why? I didn't think I added any options. I was confused.

So I deleted pkgsrc's unzip to compare ubuntu's unzip and it worked.

```
$ pkg_delete unzip

$ which unzip
/usr/bin/unzip

$ /usr/bin/unzip aaa.zip
Archive:  aaa.zip
 extracting: aaa.txt

$ls
aaa.txt aaa.zip
```

pkgsrc's unzip is broken? or did I overlook some settings I had to do?

**update(2017-2-19 14:30)**:
I'm reading the pkgsrc's source code(pkgsrc/archivers/unzip). it is generated after `bmake`.
So far, I partially changed unzip.c as following:

```
-- unzip.c --
int MAIN(argc, argv)
  int argc;
  char *argv[];
{
  int r;

  CONSTRUCTGLOBALS();

  /* for debug ----> */
  int hoge;
  printf("argc %d\n", argc);
  for(hoge = 0; hoge < argc; hoge++){
     printf("argv[%d] %s\n", hoge, argv[hoge]);
  }
  /* for debug <---- */
    r = unzip(__G__ argc, argv);
    DESTROYGLOBALS();
    RETURN(r);
} 

....
....
int unzip(__G__ argc, argv)
  __GDEF
  int argc;
  char *argv[];
{
....
....
#endif /* !NO_ZIPINFO */

      /* for debug ----> */
      printf("argc: %d\n", argc);
      printf("&argc: %d\n", &argc);
      int hoge = 0;
      for(hoge = 0; hoge < argc; hoge++){
        printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", hoge, argv[hoge]);
      }
      /* for debug <---- */

      error = uz_opts(__G__ &argc, &argv);
}

int uz_opts(__G__ pargc, pargv)
  __GDEF
  int *pargc;
  char ***pargv;
{
...
...
  while (++argv, (--argc > 0 && *argv != NULL && **argv == '-')) {
    s = *argv + 1;
    while ((c = *s++) != 0) {    /* "!= 0":  prevent Turbo C warning */

    /* for debug ----> */
    printf("c: %c\n",c);
    /* for debug <---- */

#ifdef CMS_MVS
        switch (tolower(c))
#else
        switch (c)
#endif
       {
       case ('-'):
         ++negative;
         break;
       ...
       ...
       default:
         printf("SET ERROR\n"); /* for debug */
         error = TRUE;
         break;
       }
...
...
#endif /* !SFX */
  return USAGE(error);
...
...
}

#else /* !SFX */
#  ifdef VMS
#    define QUOT '\"'
#    define QUOTS "\""
#  else
#    define QUOT ' '
#    define QUOTS ""
#  endif

int usage(__G__ error)   /* return PK-type error code */
  __GDEF
  int error;
{
  if (error){
    /* for debug ----> */
    puts("PK_PARAM: L");
    /* for debug <---- */
    return PK_PARAM;
  } else {
  ...
  }
}
```

With this change I understood argc and argv is changed before `uz_opts()` in `unzip()`. And the option `-O CP932`, which is internally added, doesn't exist in the `swich` statement in `uz_opts()`, that cause exit code 10.

```
$ unzip aaa.zip
argc 2
argv[0] unzip
argv[1] /home/xxxx/aaa.zip
argc: 4
&argc: -740106452
argv[0]: unzip
argv[1]: -O
argv[2]: CP932
argv[3]: /home/xxxx/aaa.zip
c: O
SET ERROR
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.  Send
bug reports using http://www.info-zip.org/zip-bug.html; see README for details.

Usage: unzip [-Z] [-opts[modifiers]] file[.zip] [list] [-x xlist] [-d exdir]
  Default action is to extract files in list, except those in xlist, to exdir;
  file[.zip] may be a wildcard.  -Z => ZipInfo mode ("unzip -Z" for usage).

  -p  extract files to pipe, no messages     -l  list files (short format)
  -f  freshen existing files, create none    -t  test compressed archive data
  -u  update files, create if necessary      -z  display archive comment only
  -v  list verbosely/show version info       -T  timestamp archive to latest
  -x  exclude files that follow (in xlist)   -d  extract files into exdir
modifiers:
  -n  never overwrite existing files         -q  quiet mode (-qq => quieter)
  -o  overwrite files WITHOUT prompting      -a  auto-convert any text files
  -j  junk paths (do not make directories)   -aa treat ALL files as text
  -C  match filenames case-insensitively     -L  make (some) names lowercase
  -X  restore UID/GID info                   -V  retain VMS version numbers
  -K  keep setuid/setgid/tacky permissions   -M  pipe through "more" pager
See "unzip -hh" or unzip.txt for more help.  Examples:
  unzip data1 -x joe   => extract all files except joe from zipfile data1.zip
  unzip -p foo | more  => send contents of foo.zip via pipe into program more
  unzip -fo foo ReadMe => quietly replace existing ReadMe if archive file newer
PK_PARAM: L
```

Then I checked environment variables, it is there...

```
$env
...
... 
UNZIP=-O CP932
```

**What is this?** I couldn't confirm it in my `.profile` and `.bashrc.`

Comment: I suspect some incompatibility between the zips.

Comment: @peterh The `unzip` on Ubuntu yakkety is the same.

Comment: I've just tested this with pkgsrc's unzip on Ubuntu Yakkety (16.10), and I can't reproduce it.

Comment: my pkgsrc's unzip seems totally collapse. It doesn't work even `unzip -v`. I'm trying to read the source code and insert some output for debug. Otherwise, is it better to delete all pkgsrc and re-install?  I installed postgresql server by pkgsrc, so it's helpful if I don't need to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the cause of this problem.
It was an environment variable.

```
$ env | sort
...
...
UNZIP=-O CP932
```

According to [this page](http://qiita.com/hoo89@github/items/46dcd8134061c392772f)(sorry, it is written in Japaese), this `UNZIP` variable is needed to extracting zip archives which are created in Windows and include multi byte characters such as Japanese one.
I guess this variable is imported by Ubuntu's unzip package localized as Japanese version.

So, I had to disable the UNZIP variable as bellow:

```
$ UNZIP='' unzip aaa.zip
Archive:  aaa.zip
 extracting: aaa.txt

$ ls
aaa.zip aaa.txt
```